# How to fix DNS lookup for WSL2 Ubuntu distro?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

The ip address of my Windows machine is - `172.18.16.1` and my Ubuntu WSL distro is `172.18.28.97`. The nameserver of my distro is set to windows host. I can verify that by reading the `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.18.16.1
```

When I do the lookup using `nslook` for `registry.npmjs.org`, I get following:

```
Server:         172.18.16.1
Address:        172.18.16.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.23.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.17.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.16.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.26.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.25.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.18.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.22.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.19.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.21.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.20.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.27.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.24.35
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 108.162.193.72
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 172.64.33.72
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 173.245.59.72
Name:   sandy.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 172.64.32.219
Name:   sandy.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 173.245.58.219
Name:   sandy.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 108.162.192.219
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c148
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 2a06:98c1:50::ac40:2148
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 2606:4700:58::adf5:3b48
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1b23
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1123
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1823
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1923
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1a23
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1723
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1523
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1223
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1423
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1023
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1323
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1623
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 172.64.33.72
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 173.245.59.72
Name:   bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
Address: 108.162.193.72
```

When I do the lookup using same command from Windows host, then I get completely different response:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    registry.npmjs.org
Addresses:
  2606:4700::6810:1123
  2606:4700::6810:1623
  2606:4700::6810:1323
  2606:4700::6810:1423
  2606:4700::6810:1b23
  2606:4700::6810:1923
  2606:4700::6810:1a23
  2606:4700::6810:1523
  2606:4700::6810:1723
  2606:4700::6810:1023
  2606:4700::6810:1223
  2606:4700::6810:1823
  104.16.21.35
  104.16.23.35
  104.16.26.35
  104.16.24.35
  104.16.27.35
  104.16.19.35
  104.16.22.35
  104.16.25.35
  104.16.18.35
  104.16.20.35
  104.16.17.35
  104.16.16.35
```

This causes my npm installation to break inside the WSL since it returns IP addresses for domains like `bayan.ns.cloudflare.com` and `sandy.ns.cloudflare.com`.

I flushed my windows DNS using `ipconfig /flushdns` but this doesn't solve the problem. What can I do to solve this problem?